# How to add elements of a list to existing dictionary based on key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an iterator for creating multiple lists. I need to keep adding the generated list to a dictionary dict1 based on the key value k:

```py
some value here = k

for a in jsoncontent:
list1.append(a["Value"])

dict1.setdefault(k, []).append(list1)
```

Right now I get: 
`{k:[[10,11],[12,32,6],[7,4]]}`

But I need:
`{k:[10,11,12,32,6,7,4]}`

How do I merge these lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want extend versus append.  extend inserts the contents of the list at the end of the list, while append insets its argument, a list in this case.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types